# Sprite Kit - Objective c, move multiple SKNode at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i have this method that makes the Lines

```
    lineaGuida_Img = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"LineaGuida copia.jpeg"];  
_Linea = [SKNode node];
_Linea.position = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width / 7 ) * 2, self.frame.size.height / 2 );
_Linea.zPosition = -10;

SKSpriteNode * linea = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:lineaGuida_Img];
linea.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
linea.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:linea.size];
linea.physicsBody.dynamic = FALSE;
linea.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
linea.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
[_Linea addChild:linea];

[self addChild:_Linea];
```

In the touchesBegan method when i touch the screen, the player is always on the center of screen, and those lines behind him have to move by -x.

```
  [_Linea runAction:[SKAction moveByX: -(self.size.width/8) y:0 duration:0.1]];
  [self spawn_Lines];
```

But this action is only executed by the last SKNode. I need to apply this to all Lines simultaneously. After that, when the line's position is less then the player's position, the line must be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

SpriteKit uses a tree based model,  so whatever the parent node does, the children fall suit.  Create an SKNode to house all of your lines,  add all of your lines to this SKNode, then apply the actions to the SKNode, not the lines.

Comment: i did, it's _Linea, but it doen't work, just the last node got the action.
for (int i = 0; i < nodo_LineaGuida.count; i++)
    {
        SKNode * nodo = [_Linea childNodeWithName:[nodo_LineaGuida objectAtIndex:i]];
        
        [nodo runAction:[SKAction moveByX: -(self.size.width/8) y:0 duration:0.1]];
    }

Comment: no, _Linea is only 1 node that you keep writing over and over again

Comment: Sorry..

 for (int i = 0; i < nodo_LineaGuida.count; i++)
    {
    SKNode * nodo = [_Linea childNodeWithName:[nodo_LineaGuida objectAtIndex:i]];
    [nodo runAction:[SKAction moveByX: -(self.size.width/8) y:0 duration:0.1]];
    }

tried this, but it doesn't works  :[

Comment: use your question to post code, you are posting garbled mess

Comment: when i try to use SKnode to store all the SKSpriteNode (lines) i get this error: Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'1' texture:[<SKTexture> 'LineaGuida copia.jpeg'. Can you show me an example?

Comment: you tell me what that means

Comment: I don't know, you said to create this sknode to contain the others nodes

Comment: right, the error is Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent.  that is self explanitory

Comment: No, you do not, you are already doing it, you need to understand what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Add them to NSMutableArray  to keep the reference and use for each loop to make each one run the action. I would recommend you to use NSTimer to provide [SKAction moveByX: -1 y:0 duration:0]] with constant speed which will result in the same motion as you already used. Each time this NSTimer execute you will check all positions of object from your NSMutableArray and than delete it if it fits your conditions. Be careful when you want to lose the reference completely use [object removeFromParent]; and remove it also from your NSMutableArray to avoid lose of performance later on. For this I use rather forLoop with continue method

Comment: Gwyn, please see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/5962/timed-functions-in-spritekit-skactions-vs-nstimers#t=201609251207126603466  You may want to change your answer after doing so

Comment: Thats true than the best way would be creating some "motherNode" which would contain all line children and apply this sequence to it with additional runBlock method that would check the conditions for removing line from game.